# Returning a constructed recursive data structure in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, functional-programming, recursive-datastructures, parser-combinators

I've just started learning Rust and am coming from a functional programming background. I'm trying to create a parser in rust and have defined this recursive data structure

```rust
enum SimpleExpression<'a> {
    Number(u64),
    FunctionCall(Function, &'a SimpleExpression<'a>, &'a SimpleExpression<'a>)
}
```

I initially had defined it as

```rust
enum SimpleExpression {
    Number(u64),
    FunctionCall(Function, SimpleExpression, SimpleExpression)
}
```

but got a complaint from the compiler saying this type had an infinite size. I'm not used to having to worry about managing memory so this confused me for a second but now it makes a lot of sense. Rust cannot allocate memory for a data structure where the size is not defined. So changing the `SimpleExpression` to `&'a SimpleExpression<'a>` makes sense.

The second problem I came across was when implementing the parsing function (excuse the verboseness)

```rust
fn parse_simple_expr(input: &str) -> Option<(SimpleExpression, usize)> {
    match parse_simple_expr(&input) {
        Some((left, consumed1)) => match parse_function_with_whitespace(&input[consumed1..]) {
            Some((func, consumed2)) => match parse_simple_expr(&input[consumed1+consumed2..]) {
                Some((right, consumed3)) => Some((
                    SimpleExpression::FunctionCall(func, &left.clone(), &right.clone()),
                    consumed1 + consumed2 + consumed3
                )),
                None => None
            },
            None => None
        },
        None => None
    }
}
```

But basically what is wrong with this function is I am creating `SimpleExpression` objects inside the function and then trying to return references to them from the function. The problem here of course is that the objects will be dropped when the function returns and Rust does not allow dangling references so I get the error `cannot return value referencing temporary value` on `&left.clone()` and `&right.clone()`.

It makes sense to me why this does not work but I am wondering if there is another way to execute this pattern to be able to create a recursive object and return it from a function. Or is there some fundamental reason this will never work in which case are there any good alternatives? Since my code is confusing I've also provided a simpler example of a recursive structure but that has the same limitations in case that helps to better understand the issue.

```rust
enum List<'a> {
    End,
    Next((char, &'a List<'a>))
}

fn create_linked(input: &str) -> List {
    match input.chars().next() {
        Some(c) => List::Next((c, &create_linked(&input[1..]))),
        None => List::End
    }
}
```

Comment: The usual answer to this question is to store `Box<YourType>` instead of `&YourType` inside `YourType` if it is a recursive type.

Comment: Well.. that seems to work. I will have to look more into Box to understand how it's different from a raw reference. Thank you!

Comment: If you're not already looking at this, you should read the section in The Book on Box: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html. It provides an example of a Cons list being implemented with Box, so it sounds very much in your wheelhouse!

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I was looking for thank you Connor!

Comment: Also of interest when implementing recursive structures: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)